# Problem with cv2.cvtColor() in version 4.5.4

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, matplotlib

I'm trying to display an local image, loaded with opencv v4.5.4.
My problem is that, the function cv2.cvtColor() does not do anything (the original and rgb images are the same, see below).

Thanks for your time !

```py
original_image = cv2.imread('../Movie_Poster_Dataset/2015/tt1365050.jpg')
rgb_image = cv2.cvtColor(original_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

rows = 1
columns = 2
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 7))

# Adds two subplots
fig.add_subplot(rows, columns, 1)
plt.imshow(original_image)
plt.axis('off')

fig.add_subplot(rows, columns, 2)
plt.imshow(rgb_image)
plt.axis('off')

plt.imshow(image)
plt.show()
```

**Original image:**
[image]

**My result**
[image: Left: originale_image, Right: rgb_image]

Comment: try to invert the channels manually with `rgb_img = bgr_img[:,:,::-1]` to see if the problem is actually cvtColor

Comment: It's the same with that

Comment: Something with your posted code is wrong. The line `plt.imshow(image)` gives an error `name 'image' is not defined`. What is `image`? There may be other issues, that we can't see. Please edit your code, and add the `import` statements. The sample image in your post is not `tt1365050.jpg`, because the image in your post is in PNG format (we can't tell if the issue is related to the input image).

Answer (score 0):

You can swap the red and blue color channels directly:

```py
original_image = cv2.imread('../Movie_Poster_Dataset/2015/tt1365050.jpg')
rgb_image[:, :, [0, 2]] = original_image[:, :, [2, 0]]
```